# It's possible read different format images?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've attached the below code:

```
<CardMedia
  className={classes.cardMedia}
  image={`/items/${item.ID}.svg`}
  style={{
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%",
    paddingTop: "20%",
  }}
  component="img"
/>;
```

Some items have a different format image, like `.png`, `.jpeg` or `.svg`. Is it possible to build a command to read the image independently from the format? `image={/items/${item.ID}*}`

Comment: Do the names of the images, presumably in `item.ID` include the extension? I assume not as you add hard-code them right now. Are you asking how to detect what format a file is without knowing it's path?

Comment: @Dominik If I don't specify what type of image it won't load. Most items have .svg images, but some are .png. How can I upload the image regardless of the format?

Comment: Non of the code above talks about uploading. I think we are missing a bunch of things here to be able to help you. Does the `CardMedia` component upload a file?

Comment: IMHO, the easiest way to do so is, add extension at the end of `item.ID` remove `.svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe

```
let imageFileExtentions = ['svg','jpg','png'];

...

imageFileExtentions.map((imageFileExtentions)=> (<CardMedia
  className={classes.cardMedia}
  image={`/items/${item.ID}.${imageFileExtentions}`}
  style={{
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%",
    paddingTop: "20%",
  }}
  component="img"
/>));

...
```